# Get postgresql log to show which indexes were used

Tags: postgresql

I have enabled query logging in postgresql and it's working fine, but is there a way get postgresql to also log an explain for each queries, or at least which indexes it used for each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load up `auto_explain` module:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com)